# Passing output from one command at end of another

Tags: windows, file, cmd, command, pass-through

Need to pass txt file name to another command. I have folder lets name it folder and have fileXX.txt (number at the end is changing). How can I create batch file that scans folder for tiles *.txt and passes it to another command, like print. So at the end command would look like "print file66.txt"

Comment: `for %%F in ("c:\pathto\folder\file*.txt") do print "%%~fF"`

Comment: Tried to run it, and got --->

%%F was unexpected at this time.

Comment: this is batch file syntax. To use it directly from command line, replace each `%%` with a single `%`. (Glad to see that `print` takes wildcards - much easier that way)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got myself it with command if, thanks Stephan for help and sorry for another persons time

if EXIST *.txt print *.txt